# Ввод пароля в QTextEdit

Tags: qt, qt5, pyqt5

Есть ли способ вводить пароль в QTextEdit без его отображения? Или какие другие способы есть для ввода пароля в QWidget? Я знаю про такой модуль как getpass, но как его связать с виджетом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `QLineEdit`, у него есть свойство `echoMode`, один из режимов (`Password`) рисует звездочки вместо пароля